# how to generic text instead of the url of a link

Tags: workflow, 2016, url, hyperlink

How can I show the URL of a link and display some other text instead of just URL.

Currently, the link URL will be shown like this https://www.yahoo.com

is it possible to do this instead? [link](https://www.google.com)

**Edit**:

I would like to display this in a field of a list item using workflows.

**Column type**: single line of text (open to change).

Comment: what is your column type? an what version of sharepoint ?

Comment: Can you please add some details to your question? Where do you want to show this link and its description? on page? in URL column? custom HTML file? or somewhere else?

Comment: You need to use either URL or Multiple Lines of text column. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use the URL column, you can specify the url and display text.

Comment: using a workflow? the 'set field value' step doesn't seem to be able to specify the display text

Comment: Yes there is a workaround for it. Have a look at this: https://wonderlaura.com/2013/05/30/workflow-create-a-hyperlink/

Comment: thank you! the way to do this that was stated in the link wasn't exactly usable due to differing interfaces, but the gist of it worked! i was able to set the display text by inserting <link>, <display text> in a hyperlink field!

Answer (score 0):

1. **In HTML**:

In HTML to create link you need to use anchor tag like:

```
<a href="www.google.com"> Link to Google </a>
```

2. **In Hyperlink/Picture column**:

Create **Hyperlink/Picture** column and format it as **Hyperlink**. Then while adding/updating item you will get options to add URL and its display text separately as below image:

[image]

3. **In Multiple Lines of Text(Rich text/Enhanced rich text)**:

   You can embed URL in this type of column too by click in text box, selecting **Insert** Tab and then **Link** option.

Comment: method 1 results in "<a href="__www.google.com__">here</a>" literally being output, with the bold text being the part with a link. method 2 is weird to me as my ui does not have that option. i only have 1 line to use to set the value, even when the field selected to update is a hyperlink field. method 3 has the same output as method 1